# Joining two tables of data based on date ranges as the only criterion in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `imported_files` (
  `import_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recorded_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `inserted_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `condition` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`import_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `imported_files` (`import_id`, `recorded_datetime`, `inserted_datetime`, `filename`, `condition`)
VALUES
    (293,'2019-07-20 13:51:00','2019-07-20 22:36:15','./RFID 2019-07-20 13_51.csv','rfid'),
    (294,'2019-07-20 14:32:00','2019-07-20 22:36:20','./RFID 2019-07-20 14_32.csv','rfid'),
    (295,'2019-07-20 13:52:00','2019-07-20 22:36:15','./RFID 2019-07-20 13_51.csv','rfid');

CREATE TABLE `RFID` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SortedNumber` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UID` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Antenna` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Activity` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `RFID` (`id`, `SortedNumber`, `Time`, `UID`, `Antenna`, `Activity`)
VALUES
    (161,19,'2019-07-20 14:36:17','A0 1 3 C0 0 40 11 1E',1,'Tunnel'),
    (162,18,'2019-07-20 14:23:08','A0 1 3 C0 0 40 E1 8A',1,'Tunnel'),
    (163,19,'2019-07-20 12:00:00','A0 1 3 C0 0 40 E1 8A',2,'Tunnel');
```

I am looking to associate an import_id from imported_files table with UID values in the RFID table. I am able get there part way, generating import_id's for date ranges like so:

```
SELECT import_id 
FROM imported_files 
WHERE recorded_datetime >= (SELECT `Time` FROM `RFID` ORDER BY `Time` LIMIT 1  OFFSET 1) 
  AND recorded_datetime <= (SELECT `Time` FROM `RFID` ORDER BY `Time` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 17);
```

How can I join the UID with the import_id? so that I might have an output like so:

```
import_id  UID  
---------  --------------------
294        A0 1 3 C0 0 40 E1 8A
```

Comment: What is the foreign key you are planning to do the join?

Comment: What's your `join` logic?

Comment: This one is a bit hard to answer for you without understand the reason for your OFFSET values.  The final answer is a simple JOIN query - but exactly what that query looks like depends upon the criteria that draws the relationship between the RFID.Time and the imported_files.import_id.  I sincerely hope you inherited this mess, or you're going to get a smack for bad schema design ;)

Comment: Leni there are no foreign keys, that's just not workable with the current set up. @Ragdata, the OFFSET is used to step through every date range, and to look for any records in the import_files table for those date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

With a two-step method, it is possible to find the UID in the RFID table associated with a time stamp in the imported_files tables:

**Step 1: Identify the import_id associated with date times from the RFID table:**

```
SELECT import_id FROM imported_files 
WHERE recorded_datetime >=  (SELECT `Time` FROM `RFID` ORDER BY `Time` LIMIT 1  OFFSET 17) 
AND recorded_datetime <= (SELECT `Time` FROM `RFID` ORDER BY `Time` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 18);
```

**Step 2: Find the UID associated with a particular import_id:**

```
SELECT UID,`Time` FROM RFID 
WHERE `Time` <= (SELECT recorded_datetime FROM imported_files WHERE import_id = 294) 
ORDER BY `Time` 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Hi Levi - OK, the offsets again ... what's your logic here?  If I was to try and set the OFFSET programatically, what am I looking for?  Is it the number of records contained in the PREVIOUS insert file?

Comment: The offsets allow setting the beginning and ending points of a datetime interval. Looking for datetime's in the import table that fall in between recordings found in the RFID table. Does that make sense?